# Using sort -M to sort by month

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, cat, utilities

I have a file months.txt with the following text:

```
JAN, MAR, DEC, FEB, JUN, APR
```

In bash I write the following line of code:

```
cat months.txt | sort -M
```

I assumed that this would output the text file, sorted by month. However the output is not sorted. Am I using sort incorrectly?

Comment: `sort` sorts by line. All your months are on the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort` sorts *lines* of text, and you've only given it one.

If your file looked like this:

```
JAN
MAR
DEC
FEB
JUN
APR
```

... you'd get the result you expect.

Incidentally, your command is a [useless use of cat](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html): the command

```
sort -M months.txt
```

does exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn the comma-separated list into separate lines, sort it, and then convert it back:

```
tr ',' '\n' < months.txt | sort -M | awk 'NR > 1 { printf(",") } {printf("%s", $0)} END { print "" }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another take:

```
tr -s ', ' '\n\n' < months.txt | sort -M | paste -sd,
```

```
JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,JUN,DEC
```

No whitespace in the output.